# Buddypress How to change every user's avatar url from add_filter(bp_core_fetch_avatar)?

Tags: buddypress

I am trying to change the buddypress user avatar's url. When user click other user's avatar, it will go to the user's specific field instead of the default url 'activity'. I had search through internet, I think I should add_filter bp_core_fetch_avatar to change the avatar's url, but I had tried for hours to hack, no luck. Hope somebody could help me here. Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to change the *avatar url*. You want to change the link in the href wrapped around an avatar. That link is usually handled by `bp_member_permalink()`

So try using this filter hook:

```
apply_filters( 'bp_get_member_permalink', bp_core_get_user_domain( $members_template->member->id, $members_template->member->user_nicename, $members_template->member->user_login ) );
```